# Why eclipse can't recognize LocalDate class from Java 8?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse ADT Bundle, and I updated my Java to 8 update 25 then I restart my mac. But still, eclipse can't recognize the LocalDate class. What should I do to make the eclipse recognize the LocalDate class from Java 8 update 25

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you're using [LocalDateTime](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class, not *LocalDate*. Also check your version manually to make sure you're using the version you think you do and check your java classpath if it's not right.